# Adding expiration date to SSH key

Tags: ssh, putty

I have an SSH key generated using Putty. The commen section has the creation date "rsa-key-20201015"
How can I add an expiration date for an rsa SSH key? Can it be done by editing the comment section?

Answer (score 10):

There is no place to embed the expiry date *within* the key itself. Its comment field is really just a comment field and will be ignored by the server – PuTTYgen only adds the date for your own information, it does not act as "issuance date".

However, if the server is running OpenSSH [v7.7 or later](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.7), then expiry date can be specified for a specific `authorized_keys` entry instead:

```
expiry-time="YYYYMMDD" ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz...w== Some comment
```

You can also specify exact time using `YYYYMMDDhhmm` (the default is midnight 00:00). For example, if you specify `20201030`, the entry will stop being accepted at 2020-10-30 00:00:00.

(Note that the actual key does not change at all – it's still in the same format and it still doesn't have any expiry date "built in", only the `authorized_keys` file does.)

Older systems do not support this feature, and would need manual cron scripting via the comment field. For reference:

- Debian 10 (Buster) and Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) have OpenSSH v7.9 and support this feature.
- Debian 9 (Stretch) and Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) have OpenSSH v7.2/v7.4 and *do not* support it.

---

*OpenSSH also has a different key format (known as "SSH certificates") which does allow embedding expiry date. However, certificates cannot be used with PuTTY, WinSCP, or Bitvise clients – they're only compatible with OpenSSH itself (i.e. the `ssh` client). More documentation about this functionality: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Certificate-based_Authentication*